# How do you say "Kind reminder" in context of an email?

Tags: english-to-german, letter

How do you write the generic "Kind reminder" email in German?

"Generic" as in to someone you don't typically know or have any relationship.

Comment: A bit of context would be helpful, especially on how intimate you are with the receiver.  You tend to write different types of messages to people you have known for ages than to mostly unknown persons.

Comment: Nothing an online dictionary can't solve, hence your question will soon be closed. If you have further details that can't be found by Google alone, please edit your question.

Comment: @tofro it's kind of a formal contact, someone I don't know

Comment: @RoyPJ It's hard to tell from "Google alone" what is the appropriate words to use not to sound overly arrogant or insensitive, I searched through a couple of websites that provide idioms and search through translated complete texts to find something appropriate before posting here

Comment: @RoyPJ check this question:
https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38166/how-to-say-btw-in-german?rq=1

it's literally in every online translate service there is, yet it's a question with 51 upvotes

Comment: You simply put **Erinnerung:** in the subject line, and **Zu ihrer Erinnerung, …** at the beginning of the text, just below the greeting.

Comment: @MysticOdin You could improve your question by adding/summarise the results of your search. Then people could tell you about the usage of the examples you've found.

Comment: @Janka That looks like the beginning of a good answer and should not be hidden in comments (and bypass the quality control)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to say “gentle reminder” in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34499/what-is-the-best-way-to-say-gentle-reminder-in-german)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wand to express it a friendly way, take "Freundliche Erinnerung", otherwise just "Erinnerung" or "Zu Ihrer Erinnerung".

Comment: Oder 'höfliche'.